# SwiftUI CoreData not in Set of relationships

Tags: swift, macos, core-data, swiftui

I am having a CoreData structure. It is working fine for me. Now I am trying to do an interesting `FetchRequest`, however I am struggeling to find the correct `predicate`.

I am having two ententies, `Person` and `Venues`. A person can be connected to many venues, but only once to the same `venue`. And other way around.

I have created a mapping table, which saves the `person` and `venue` as relationships. Everything is working fine here. I even implemented the `inverse` relationship.

[image]

In the picture left is my venue. I want to Fetch all `persons` based on a current venue, where there is **NO Mapping** created already.

My approach was to use `pk_venue`, which gives me a set of `PersonVenueMapping`. However, how can I only use the `persons` of that Set.

```
fetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "NOT (person IN %@)", venue!.pk_venue[HELP])
```

I came up with that Predicate. However, how can I access the persons of that set? I would need a array/ set of only the `persons`, that are connected to that current object.

**Edit:** Just to give you example.

*Person*: Max, Leon, Henry
*Venue*: Venue1, Venue2, Venue 3, Venue 4

*PersonVenueMapping*: Max <-> Venue1

Now when I select `Max`, I want `Venue2` & `Venue3` & `Venue4`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need a mapping entity, why not create a many-to-many mapping between Person and Venue?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thanks for answering..  I need to store an attribute to that relationship, which is my role. Can I use your approach with three realtionships aswell?

Comment: No but maybe you don't need 3 relationships like that depending on what a role is in this context.

Comment: Your example is kinda wage. If you select Max you want all the venues not in the PersonVenueMapping Table?

Comment: Unfortunately I need that role for each Mapping individual

Comment: @Mamaessen Yeah it is correct. I want all venues where Max is not connected to, so where there is not entry in the mapping table with Max.

Comment: If the design is that a Person has a Role for a Venue then the relationships should mirror that.

Comment: This seems very much like you are treating CoreData like a database when it actually isn’t one. Model your data in a way that the app will display it. Not in a way that a normalised SQLite database might look.

Comment: @Fogmeister Thanks.. yes you are right. I am still getting used to CoreData coming from regular relational databases. You also mean I won't need a mapping table?

Comment: @davidev yes, that's what I mean. I've added an answer that shows how that would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model looks very much like a normalised database type model. CoreData is not a database and so some of the requirements of modelling data are more flexible when using it. For instance `many to many` relationships are possible (and encouraged).

Create your model in this way...

```
Person
------
name: String
------
assignedVenues: Many relationship to `venue` type
```

Now every relationship has an inverse property, so...

```
Venue
------
name: String
------
managers: Many relationship to `Person` type
```

Now you can go from Max to his assigned venues just by doing...

```
let selectedPerson = // fetch Max from CoreData

let venues = selectedPerson.assignedVenues
```

Equally you can go from a venue to find all the people managing it...

```
let someVenue = // fetch venue from CoreData

let managers = someVenue.managers
```

To satisfy your question of finding all venues that Max is not managing you can now do a query like...

```
let selectedPerson = //fetch Max

let predicate = NSPredicate(format:"NONE managers == %@", selectedPerson) // Its been a long time since I did CoreData so forgive me if this syntax isnt correct but the idea is correct. :D
```

You can now use that predicate to get all `venues` where max is NOT one of the managers of the venue.

By removing the "mapping" that is required in something like SQLite etc... you can make things much simpler for yourself.

Comment: Wow.. thanks for taking the time and writing that down :) I appreciate. Really learned something very helpful again. I will make changes to my CoreData structure and try your query aswell.

Comment: @davidev Glad I could help. :D There are some really excellent tutorials on https://www.raywenderlich.com that cover a lot of really useful tips on how to use CoreData. Definitely worth a read.

Comment: Still one question arise.. I still need to store a role for one relationship. However, I can not store that attribute in the person entity or venue as there can be more relationships with different roles. How can I use that in your approach?

Comment: In that case you could possibly replace your `Mapping` type with `Role` and use that as the mapping. I guess it comes down to your specific model requirements which would take a while to look in to. So you could just have `Person <->> Role <<-> Venue` or something like that. There might be other better ways of doing this also. With this I think your venue predicate could be something like `NONE jobs.manager == %@` but now I'm going beyond what my memory is able to store. :D Where `jobs` is the many relationship from `venue ->> role`

Answer (score 1):

I am confused as to whether you are fetching persons with no mapping to a given venue, or venues with no mapping to a given person.  I’ll assume the latter.

Your fetch request will therefore be for the entity Venue.  Let’s call the selected Person `selectedPerson`.  The following predicate should return only those Venues that have no mapping to `selectedPerson`:

```
NSPredicate(format:”SUBQUERY(pk_venue, $M, $M.person == %@).@count == 0”, selectedPerson)
```

or in natural language “fetch Venues for which the count of mappings ($M), with `person` equal to the selected person, is zero”.

Comment: Appreciate the answer sir. Will test, yeah it is indeed correct what you said at the end. That is what I want to achieve